# KeyCloak 2.3 getting NPE when exporting

Tags: java, jboss, keycloak

My KeyCloak works with h2 db(default) and has some data in it
i want to export the data so i can migrate KeyCloak to mysql

KeyCloak i'm using is 2.3 version 
I keep getting the NPE when trying to export the data.

Command that i'm using for exporting is:

sudo ./standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile -Dkeycloak.migration.file=/tmp/export.json

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.keycloak.exportimport.util.ExportUtils.exportRealm(ExportUtils.java:227)
at org.keycloak.exportimport.singlefile.SingleFileExportProvider$1.runExportImportTask(SingleFileExportProvider.java:65)
at org.keycloak.exportimport.util.ExportImportSessionTask.run(ExportImportSessionTask.java:35)
at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:235)
at org.keycloak.exportimport.singlefile.SingleFileExportProvider.exportModel(SingleFileExportProvider.java:58)
at org.keycloak.exportimport.ExportImportManager.runExport(ExportImportManager.java:102)
at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:148)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:150)
... 19 more
```

Comment: Maybe your H2 database is corrupt. Do you have more than one realm defined? If so have you tried exporting only the single realm that has your users  -Dkeycloak.migration.realmName=<your_realm>

Comment: I have two realms master and one with users. I get same error with  -Dkeycloak.migration.realmName=<your_realm>. I dont think that h2 is corrupted i can see the data in administration console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by reading H2  and creating sql script for generating tables + data

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same issue but I was also getting a Null pointer error when trying to do a default export.

The issue for me was due to not setting the alias for an execution in the authentication flow.
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-2494

Basically to maintain ordering of the exported Json files and keep them versionable keycloak is requiring an alias be set so that it can always do consistent sorting.

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/commit/c81d0c0898d7b44c0d053ce6666acdad4967bffc

The fix for me was to set an alias field in the config for the execution through the admin console, annoyingly if you've done any configuration before it won't let you update the alias. You'll have to just delete the execution in the admin console and recreate it.